# How can I access network folders and files as the current user?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a C# .NET windows desktop application, I am trying to access a network location using DirectoryInfo but it is unable to access as requires an authenticated user.

The current user has the required access and can access the folder using Windows file explorer.

I tried impersonating by wrapping my code inside of...

```
WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
using (wi.Impersonate())
{
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder.Text);
    //etc
}
```

...but same result.

How can I use DirectoryInfo and other File functions in the context of the current user?

Comment: You should automatically have the user access except if the access is Admin.  If you are not getting access inside c# it is probably because you are running inside Visual Studio.  Try starting VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin. Then try your code.  When running a VS executable it will automatically run with Admin, but inside VS you need to right click the shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Also when you are an Admin in the path name you need to replace the colon with a dollar sign : c$\folder

Comment: "current user has the required access" clearly they don't, or the user isn't the one you think it is. Impersonating the same user doesn't make a huge amount of sense. Is the app being used in a double-hop situation (eg remote desktop)?

Comment: The current user can access the network folder with \\server\folder using Windows Explorer but can't when running the app in or out of VS, as admin or not as admin. I thought that the app would run as the current user context but assumed not when I ran into this error. Am presently connected via VPN, but not RDP.

Comment: just to exclude formatting issues, did you try the UNC path as a string directly? Just for testing. DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\YourServer\YourFolder");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to connect to the network drives using a UNC path, but I did find a workaround.

I mapped the drives to a drive letter and my application was then able to access the files and folders by driver letter instead of UNC path.